Picker from the toolbar in watchOS (SwiftUI)
What I'm trying to do is to display a picker in watchOS: this picker will have only 4 options, so I would like it to be in the style of .navigationLink.
Currently I have this code inside a view and everything works fine (DateRange is an enum):
Picker(selection: $dateRange) {
    Text("Today").tag(DateRange.today)
    Text("This week").tag(DateRange.thisWeek)
    Text("Last 7 days").tag(DateRange.lastSevenDays)
    Text("Last 30 days").tag(DateRange.lastThirtyDays)
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")
}
.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)

What I'd like to do is to move this picker to the toolbar: I've seen that by wrapping it in a ToolbarItem everything works, but the current selection is displayed in the toolbar button, and this breaks the layout (the string doesn't fit).
Moreover, when the picker appears from the toolbar the options still work, but are grayed out, as if they were disabled.
Is there a way to have a picker appear when clicking on a toolbar item, but not showing the selection and being "enabled"?

The button works for me, but I can't hide the default picker label on WatchOS. Any label I made appears alongside the default picker label.
